# Upgrading google-cloud-sdk Fails on Configure

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Upgrading gcloud on Ubuntu 16.04 fails on postinst configuration. The google-cloud-sdk has been installed and used without installation problems, but this is aborting the upgrade at the configuration phase. The problem seems to be that the postinst script is executing a Python3 script with the Python2 interpreter, which fails on a Python3 syntax line.

---

```
# sudo dpkg --configure google-cloud-sdk
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (131.0.0-0) ...
dpkg: error processing package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-cloud-sdk

dpkg: error processing package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-cloud-sdk


# sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 google-cloud-sdk
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: process queue pkg google-cloud-sdk:all queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1
D000040: checking dependencies of google-cloud-sdk:all (- <none>)
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> python2.7
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg python2.7:amd64
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<
D000040:     checking Breaks
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (131.0.0-0) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/google-cloud-sdk.postinst ( configure 129.0.0-0 )
dpkg: error processing package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-cloud-sdk


# sudo /usr/bin/gcloud components post-process

Compiling platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py ...
  File "platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python3/httplib2/__init__.py", line 350
    print('%s:' % h, end=' ', file=self._fp)
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

ERROR: gcloud crashed (CommandLoadFailure): Problem loading gcloud.dns.record-sets.import: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAA'.

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback


# sudo which python; sudo python --version
/usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.12

# sudo which python3; sudo python3 --version
/usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.2
```

---

```
Trace:
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/gcloud_main.py:130
 gcloud_cli.Execute()
  [...]
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1630
 resources = command_instance.Run(args)
surface/components/post_process.py:40
 table.Update(self.cli)
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/command_lib/static_completion/table.py:154
 table = CompletionTableGenerator(cli).Wa...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/walker.py:98
 root.LoadAllSubElements(recursive=True)
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1490
 element.LoadAllSubElements(recursive=rec...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1490
 element.LoadAllSubElements(recursive=rec...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1488
 element = self.LoadSubElement(name)
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1528
 parent_group=self)
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1592
 self._GetModuleFromPath(module_dir, modu...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/calliope/backend.py:1258
 name_to_give, os.path.join(module_dir, *...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/core/util/pkg_resources.py:108
 module = imp.load_module(name_to_give, f...
surface/dns/record_sets/import.py:19
 from googlecloudsdk.api_lib.dns import i...
/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/api_lib/dns/import_util.py:162
 rdatatype.CAA: _CAATranslation,
CommandLoadFailure: Problem loading gcloud.dns.record-sets.import: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAA'.
[output truncated]
```

---

```
# sudo gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 131.0.0
alpha 2016.10.17
beta 2016.10.17
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2016.10.17
core-nix 2016.10.17
gcloud 
gsutil 4.21
gsutil-nix 4.21
```

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem on a Google Compute Engine instance running Ubuntu 16.04, and I was able to resolve it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove google-cloud-sdk
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)"
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/partner.list
sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Comment: Yes, I tried removing and re-adding the repo that way, but it didn't help. Only trying for a few upgrades until it finally worked. Google's team was responsive in the ticket, but were never able to explain why their SW was trying to run Python 3 code in a Python 2.7 interpreter. Eventually it just worked without explanation. Hope it doesn't happen again.

Comment: You need a vital 

`
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add - ; 
sudo apt-get update
`
before trying  `sudo apt-get instal ....`

Comment: @Matthew How did you resolved this error , Becuase same error is happening to me

Comment: @twister_void "Eventually it just worked without explanation." Maybe Stoian's curl hit works, I dunno.

Answer (score 5):

The direct cause may be a lack of memory.
Try to add swap before upgrading.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap bs=2048 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /var/swap
sudo mkswap /var/swap
sudo swapon /var/swap
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I didn't add swap or anything else, either explicitly or implicitly within the subsequent updates to the google-cloud-sdk , but eventually an update caused it to start working again.

Comment: @Matthew I knew that. My answer is for those who have the same issue and still suffers.

Comment: I'm doing things on a GCE Micro instance; it never struck me that it might be insufficient memory until now. This solved everything. \o/

Comment: (Well, almost everything ;)

Answer (score 0):

All I did was apply the **autoremove** flag and it reinstalled on its own fixing itself. It took forever to run on my small instance but it did finally work.

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Since the package was **python-dialog** that was removed, I'm guessing that was the issue... at least for me. :-)

## Edit:

Since my google instance was the smallest one possible, there was not enough memory to complete the task. Once I stopped the web server and all PM2 tasks, it finally finished without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Problem loading `gcloud.dns.record-sets.import: 'module' object has no attribute 'CAA'.`

Cause:

Older Python Packages installed.

I suppose it is an old `dnspython`

If you use pip:

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip install -U
```

All pip packages will be updated

If you use `easy_install` you need to check manually

Answer (score -1):

adhere following commands

IF YOU COME ACROSS ANY LOCK USE "SUDO RM  TO REMOVE

`sudo rm /usr/bin/click`

RECTIFY THE BROKEN LIBRARIES

`sudo apt autoremove -f click`

UPDATES & UPGRADES LIBRARIES

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: It will rectify the broken libraries

Comment: Maybe one or two explaining sentences would be nicer.

Comment: No reason to shout ;-)

Comment: WHY NOT?!?!?!?!