# Installing google-cloud-sdk on a GCE Micro (Debian) instance

Tags: debian, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

In the instructions for installing `google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python`, it runs you through installing the gcloud SDK. It starts out innocent enough:

I would run `sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk` and get this:

```
[...]
Setting up google-cloud-sdk (178.0.0-0) ...
Killed
dpkg: error processing package google-cloud-sdk (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 137
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-cloud-sdk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Part of my thinking behind setting up an instance on Google Compute Engine was to utilize Google's infrastructure under the impression that *maybe it would connect to other parts of Google's infrastructure better,* or at least more simply, than doing it from EC2 (or others). Alas... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some decent amount of head-scratching, I came across [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46029031/1302400) and it dawned on me that my micro instance was suffering from lack of memory during installation:

> The direct cause may be a lack of memory. Try to add swap before upgrading.
>
> ```
> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap bs=2048 count=524288
> sudo chmod 600 /var/swap
> sudo mkswap /var/swap
> sudo swapon /var/swap
> sudo apt upgrade
> ```

Upon completion, the installation statements finally worked as one would expect.